# Why Can't the Mother be Returned to the Heavens? (Spoilers)

Tags: la-mulana

In the Twin Labyrinths, there is a tablet which says that the Four Philosophers, after studying the ruins of La Mulana, have decided that the Mother cannot be returned to the heavens, and so she must be killed.

The Giants have already built the Tower of the Goddess, Spring in the Sky, Inferno Cavern and Tower of Ruin for the express purpose of returning the Mother to the heavens. Couldn't the Seventh and Eighth Children use that, despite the Giants' failure?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is about 3 years too late, but they couldn't return her to the heavens simply because she'd grown too large.

To put it another way, the entirety of La-Mulana **is** the Mother.  Meaning that she is actually quite large.

Comment: She is quite large, but she was quite large to begin with.